# If $G$ is a finite subgroup of $GL_n(C)$ then there is a polynomial $f\in C[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $f(gv)=f(v)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

**Problem.** Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $\textrm{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ and $a \in \Bbb C^n-\{0\}$. Show that there is some polynomial $f \in \Bbb C[x_1,~\cdots,x_n]$ that satisfies the following conditions.

(1) $f(gv) = f(v)$ for all $g\in G$ and $v\in \Bbb C^n$.

(2) $f(0) = 0$ and $f(a) = 1$.

I'm trying to solve this problem. The condition $f(0)=0$ means that $f$ should have no constant term. Also to be $f(a)=1$, it suffices to have $f(a)\neq 0$, because we can normalize at the end. I got stuck here. I can't see how to use the assumption that $G$ is a finite subgroup of $GL_n(C)$. What I know about it is, that every $g\in G$ should be diagonalizable because $g$ has finite order, and so the minimal polynomial of $g$ splits. But I'm not sure that this fact is useful. Any hints?

Comment: Something that comes to mind: if $G$ is a set of complex-orthogonal matrices, then  $f(\mathbf x) = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$ is a polynomial fulfilling the requirements

Comment: I think this might help: take $f$ to be a polynomial of (sufficiently large) degree $d$.  For each $g \in G$, $f(g \mathbf x) = f(\mathbf x)$ can be rewritten system of polynomial equations on the coefficients of $f$. Considering $f(g \mathbf x) = \mathbf x$ for all $g \in G$ gives us an even bigger (but finite) such system of equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest construction is as follow: Let $h(v)$ be any non-trivial polynomial, and then let

$$f(v) = \prod_{g \in G} h(gv).$$

It's both non-constant and invariant by $G$. If $h$ was homogenous of degree one, then $f$ is homogenous of degree $|G|$.

More generally, if $V$ is the representation of $G$ on the linear terms, then one can study the ring of  $G$-invariants $k[V]^{G}$. Hilbert proved that this ring is always finitely generated. It's also easy to show it has transcendence degree $n$. This goes under the name "invariant theory".

Comment: The question requires $f(a)\neq0$,so you need to choose an $h$ that doesn't vanish at any of the points $ga$. Considering only linear polynomials, the "bad" $h$'s constitute the union of finitely many proper linear subspaces of the dual space, so *almost* every $h$ is good.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes indeed! I confess I simply read the question as "find a non-constant invariant"

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$, $Y$ disjoint Zariski closed subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$.  The system

$f=0$, $f\in I(X)$

$g=0$, $g \in I(Y)$

has not solution. By [Hilbert nulstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz), the sum of the ideals $I(X)$, $I(Y)$ is $1$. So there exists $f \in I(X)$, $g\in I(Y)$ so that 
$$f+ g = 1$$  Therefore the polynomial $f$ is $0$ on $X$ and $1$ on $Y$.

Assume moreover that $X$, $Y$ are $G$ invariant. Consider $f^G$ the $G$ average of $f$.  We have $f^G$ is $G$ invariant, $f^G=0$ on $X$ and $=1$ on $Y$.